# Error al crear un objeto array en PHP

Tags: php, array, clase, properties

tengo un problema con PHP y requiero de su ayuda para entenderlo, aquí tengo mi código, cree unos atributos como array para almacenar información:

#### Mascota.php

```php
<?php
    class mascota {
      //Atributos
      public $tipo = array(); 
      public $nombre = array(); 
      public $color = array(); 
      public $raza = array(); 
      public $edad = array(); 
      
      // Métodos
      
      public function mostrarMascota($nro,$tp,$nom,$col,$raz,$ed) {
        array_push($tipo,$tip);
        array_push($nombre,$nom);
        array_push($color,$col);
        array_push($raza, $raz);
        array_push($edad,$ed);
        
        $respuesta = 
          "
          <table BORDER>
            <tr>
              <td>
                $tipo[$nro];
              </td>
              <td>
                $nombre[$nro]; 
              </td>
              <td>
                $color[$nro];
              </td>
              <td>
                $raza[$nro];
              </td>
              <td>
                $edad[$nro];
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>";
          
         return $respuesta: 
        
      }
    }
?>
```

#### Index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1.0">
  <title>LABORATORIO NRO 3 - INGENIERÍA WEB</title>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="container">
    <h1>LABORATORIO NRO3 - INGENIERÍA WEB</h1>
    <div class="creando-objeto">
      <h2>Creación del objeto mascota</h2>
      <table BORDER>
        <tr>
          <th>Mascota</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tipo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Nombre</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Color</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Raza</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Edad</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      <?php
      
        include('./Modelo/Mascota.php');
        
        $objMascota = new mascota();
        echo $objMascota->mostrarMascota(0,"PERRO","MILANESO","NEGRO",
        "PASTOR ALEMAN",5);
      
      ?>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

El resultado es este, recien estoy aprendiendo php y me parece que es un problema de los arrays que estoy haciendo mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero que nada... el código es texto, qué te hace pensar que tratarlo como imágenes da buena impresión?? Si ni te esfuerzas un poquito en elaborar una pregunta siguiendo las reglas ([ask], [help]), no creo que debamos esforzarnos nosotros por ayudarte... De todas maneras, y sin haber tocado php en años, creo recordar que los atributos de la clase se acceden como `$this->tipo`, y no `$tipo` directamente. Eso si, por favor, utiliza el botón [edit] y pon el código y los errores como texto...

Comment: lo que es codigo colocalo como codigo(texto) los errores dejalas como imagen... has estos cambios para poder ayudarte, no pienso transcribir todo tu codigo... su no tienes el tiempo de aprender a usar el sitio por que deberia yo de usar mi tiempo para transcribir codigo?

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: por lo menos has investigado que son esos warning y errores?

Comment: Hola si disculpa, estaré leyendo el centro de ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comprendo que estás empezando. Es como dice @Benito-B, se debe usar `$this` para referirse a todos los miembros no estáticos de una clase.

Por otra parte, se notan errores de lógica en tu código. Si la intención es crear elementos en una posición específica de cada array, debes indicarlo explícitamente, al usar `array_push()` los elementos se meterán empezando por el principio, de modo que si en el primer parámetro pasas un valor diferente de `0` la construcción de la tabla fallará. Además, `array_push` es más costoso, y deberías evitarlo. Sea como sea, **diseñar una clase como lo estás haciendo es inviable, y se aleja totalmente del propósito de la POO, revisa la Post-Data donde abundaré sobre esto**.

Además, con respecto a `$respuesta`, debes terminar la línea con punto y coma, y no puedes usar esas llamadas como las tienes, todo dentro de una comilla. Para los miembros de la clase debes usar `{}`, por ejemplo:

```
$respuesta = 
    "Lorem ipsum {$this->nombre[$index]} dolor sit amet {$this->edad[$index]}";
```

O bien usar `sprintf()`, he preferido esto último.

Por último, la *convención de nombre* es importante. No uses variables que nadie sabe lo que significan, tales como `$tp,$col,$raz,$ed`, dentro de un mes, ni tú mismo sabrás si `$col` se refiere a una columna, a un color ... si `$ed` se refiere a la edad o a eduardo, etc. A ser posible, usa nombres en inglés para tus variables.

Propongo este código (para resolver los errores que planteas en la pregunta):

```
class mascota {
  //Atributos
  public $type = array(); 
  public $name = array(); 
  public $color = array(); 
  public $race = array(); 
  public $age = array(); 
  
  // Métodos
  
  public function mostrarMascota($index,$type,$name,$color,$race,$age) {
    $this->type[$index]=$type;
    $this->name[$index]=$name;
    $this->color[$index]=$color;
    $this->race[$index]=$race;
    $this->age[$index]=$age;
    $outPut = 
        sprintf("
      <table BORDER>
        <tr>
          <td>
            %s
          </td>
          <td>
            %s 
          </td>
          <td>
            %s
          </td>
          <td>
            %s
          </td>
          <td>
            %s
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>",
              $this->type[$index],
              $this->name[$index],
              $this->color[$index],
              $this->race[$index],
              $this->age[$index])
              ;
      
     return $outPut;
    
  }
}
```

Y para probar:

```
$mMascota=new mascota();
echo $mMascota->mostrarMascota(1,"Perro","Perro one","Blanco","Pastor",2);
```

**Salida:**

```
      <table BORDER>
        <tr>
          <td>2
            Perro
          </td>
          <td>
            Perro one 
          </td>
          <td>
            Blanco
          </td>
          <td>
            Pastor
          </td>
          <td>
            2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

---

### Post-Data

Como mencioné más arriba, el diseño actual de tu clase es inviable y se aleja del propósito de la POO.

Debes pensar las clases que representan entidades como moldes para construir **uno o más objetos de ese tipo**. Tu clase actual manejaría un array de mascotas, si realmente necesitas eso, deberás construir otra clase que las coleccione, y **no cometer el error de meter esa lógica dentro de la misma clase `Mascota`**, porque en algún contexto, sin duda, necesitarás trabajar con **una sola mascota** o presentar/mapear los datos individualizados.

Veamos un ejemplo, donde he creado una clase llamada `MascotaList` que gestiona un array de objetos del tipo `Mascota`.

Esta sería la clase `Mascota` modificada. NÓTESE que los miembros de la misma **no son arrays**, sino variables simples que representan cada campo de la entidad. He añadido algunos métodos que nos serán útiles más adelante y he creado un constructor para pasar los atributos al crear la instancia de la clase (luego puedes crear *setter* también por si necesitas modificar algún atributo una vez creada la instancia).

#### `Mascota`

```
class Mascota {
  //Atributos
  private $type; 
  private $name; 
  private $color; 
  private $race; 
  private $age; 
  
  // Métodos
  
  public function __construct($type,$name,$color,$race,$age) {
    $this->type=$type;
    $this->name=$name;
    $this->color=$color;
    $this->race=$race;
    $this->age=$age;
  }
  
  // Getters  
  public function getType() {
      return $this->type;
  }
    
  public function getName() {
      return $this->name;
  }    
    
  public function getColor() {
      return $this->color;
  }

  public function getRace() {
      return $this->race;
  }    
    
  public function getAge() {
      return $this->age;
  }    
    
  public function printData() {
      return sprintf("Tipo: %s\nNombre: %s\nColor:  %s\nRaza: %s\nEdad:  %s",
                     $this->type,$this->name,$this->color,$this->race,$this->age);
  }    
    
}
```

Ahora veamos otra clase que nos servirá para **coleccionar** mascotas.

#### `MascotaList`

```
class MascotaList {
  //Atributos
  private $list=array(); 

  
  // Métodos
  public function __construct() {

  }
    
  public function addMascota(Mascota $mascota) {
      $this->list[]=$mascota;
  }
    
  public function getList() {
      return $this->list;
  }        
    
  public function printTable() {
      $rowTemplate="<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>";
      $table="<table BORDER>";
      foreach ($this->list as $m) {
          $table.=sprintf($rowTemplate,$m->getType(),$m->getName(),$m->getColor(),$m->getRace(),$m->getAge());
      }
      $table.="</table>";
      return $table;   
  }
}
```

Si observas, ahora `Mascota` es un objeto independiente, y puedes crear colecciones de mascota mediante `MascotaList`. Veamos un ejemplo contextual:

```
$listMascotas=new MascotaList();
$listMascotas->addMascota(new Mascota("Perro","Rex","Blanco","Raza de Rex",2));
$listMascotas->addMascota(new Mascota("Gato","Félix","Marrón","Raza de Félix",1));
$listMascotas->addMascota(new Mascota("Perro","Tintín","Negro","Raza de Tintín",3));
echo $listMascotas->printTable();
```

**Salida:**

```
<table BORDER>
   <tr>
      <td>Perro</td>
      <td>Rex</td>
      <td>Blanco</td>
      <td>Raza de Rex</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Gato</td>
      <td>Félix</td>
      <td>Marrón</td>
      <td>Raza de Félix</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Perro</td>
      <td>Tintín</td>
      <td>Negro</td>
      <td>Raza de Tintín</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Pero, imaginemos que necesitas datos de una mascota en específico, por ejemplo, la primera mascota de la colección, y que quieres otro formato, no una tabla.

Si observas, la clase `Mascota` tiene un método `printData()` que fue creado para ese propósito.

**Sin modificar nada en las clases**, puedes satisfacer este nuevo requerimiento con esta línea de código:

```
echo $listMascotas->getList()[0]->printData();
```

**Salida:**

```
Tipo: Perro
Nombre: Rex
Color:  Blanco
Raza: Raza de Rex
Edad:  2
```

O, imaginemos que, en vez de una tabla, necesitas imprimir la colección de mascotas del modo anterior, basta con agregar este método a `MascotaList`:

```
public function printData() {
    $outPut="";
    foreach ($this->list as $m) {
        $outPut.=$m->printData().PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $outPut;   
}
```

Ahora, podrás hacer esto desde cualquier contexto:

```
echo $listMascotas->printData();
```

**Salida:**

```
Tipo: Perro
Nombre: Rex
Color:  Blanco
Raza: Raza de Rex
Edad:  2

Tipo: Gato
Nombre: Félix
Color:  Marrón
Raza: Raza de Félix
Edad:  1

Tipo: Perro
Nombre: Tintín
Color:  Negro
Raza: Raza de Tintín
Edad:  3
```

En conclusión, tu modelo de datos debería poder adaptarse a diferentes contextos, pudiendo resolver con una misma clase todas las situaciones que se presenten: manejar una o más mascotas, mostrar los datos de una forma o de otra, etc.

Por poner un caso de uso muy frecuente. Supongamos que en un contexto necesitas obtener datos de una mascota **desde una tabla de la base de datos**, y en otro contexto desde un `.json` expuesto en una API y en otro contexto desde un `.xml` ofrecido por un Servicio Web. Pues bien, la clase `Mascota` que hemos diseñado más arriba **te servirá para  mapear resultados de mascota en los tres contextos**. Esta es una de las grandes ventajas de la POO. Si no diseñas teniendo esto presente, pronto tendrás un spaghetti en el código y para los tres casos de uso antes mencionados estarás creando tres clases que al final hacen lo mismo ...

---

### Demo

Finalmente, te dejo una demostración en línea del código implementado en la Post-Data, por si quieres hacer pruebas que ayuden a entender mejor la POO.

<kbd>[**`VER DEMO EN REXTESTER`**](https://rextester.com/HKQEE96099)</kbd>

Espero que te sea de utilidad. Cualquier duda, puedes preguntar en el área de comentarios.

Comment: Esta es la solución, gracias, una duda más, en el código que propones, los arrays si almacenan los valores de mostrarMascota verdad?

Comment: @Christian revisa la **Post-Data**. En la respuesta inicial, lo que hace `mostrarMascota()` es asignar al array cada propiedad en la posición de `$index`. No obstante, un diseño así no tiene sentido, por lo que explico en la **Post-Data**. Además en las clases, por lo general, las propiedades se asignar en el constructor o mediante métodos *setter*. Un método *mostrar* debería servir que para lo que describe, para *mostrar* datos, no para *agregar* datos. Sea como sea, cuando diseñas una clase que represente a una entidad, deberías pensarla como un objeto independiente.

Answer (score 2):

1- Falta el `;` en `return $respuesta;`

2- El 2do argumento de `MostrarMascota` no es `$tp`, es `$tip`

3- Estás definiendo atributos (`$tipo`, `$nombre`,...), pero dentro del método estás tratando de escribir variables locales que no existen. Para poder acceder a estas variables usar la palabra `$this->`

4- Estás usando una estructura de datos incorrecta para lo que pretendes hacer. Usa un array asociativo

5- Esto es basado en opiniones, pero puedes realizar la asignación de parámetros en el constructor `__construct()`, o si no crea un método para ingresar los datos y otro para desplegarlos. No tiene mucho sentido crear una clase que su único método reciba una lista de parámetros y los devuelva como html.

En esta propuesta, modifiqué tu código con un atributo `data`, el cual va acumulando las mascotas, y le puedes seguir agregando más:

```php
<?php
class mascota {
    //Atributos
    public $data = array();
    
    public function ingresarMascota($nro, $tip, $nom, $col, $raz, $ed) {
        $this->data[$nro]['tip'] = $tip;
        $this->data[$nro]['nom'] = $nom;
        $this->data[$nro]['col'] = $col;
        $this->data[$nro]['raz'] = $raz;
        $this->data[$nro]['ed'] = $ed;
    }

    public function mostrarMascota($nro) {
        // Aqui va tu salida HTML, solo se puso string para simplificar
        $var = $this->data[$nro];
        return "Tipo: $var[tip], Nombre: $var[nom], Color: $var[col],...";
    }
}

$objMascota = new mascota();
$objMascota->ingresarMascota(0,"PERRO","MILANESO","NEGRO","PASTOR ALEMAN",5);
$objMascota->ingresarMascota(1,"GATO","JULIANA","CALICO","GATO COMUN",3);
$objMascota->ingresarMascota(2,"COBAYO","ISIDRO","BLANCO","INDEFINIDO",2);

// Obteniendo salidas:
echo $objMascota->mostrarMascota(0); // Tipo: PERRO, Nombre: MILANESO, Color: NEGRO,...
echo $objMascota->mostrarMascota(1); // Tipo: GATO, Nombre: JULIANA, Color: CALICO,...
```

---

Otra forma, usando un constructor para definir cada mascota como un objeto, se renombró el método `mostrarMascota` a simplemente `mostrar` y no es necesario un array acumulador:

```php
<?php
class mascota {
   
    public function __construct($tip, $nom, $col, $raz, $ed) {
        $this->tip = $tip;
        $this->nom = $nom;
        $this->col = $col;
        $this->raz = $raz;
        $this->ed = $ed;
    }

    public function mostrar() {
        // Aqui va tu salida HTML, solo se puso string para simplificar
        return "Tipo: $this->tip, Nombre: $this->nom, Color: $this->col,...";
    }
}

$pet1 = new mascota("PERRO","MILANESO","NEGRO","PASTOR ALEMAN",5);
$pet2 = new mascota("GATO","JULIANA","CALICO","GATO COMUN",3);
$pet3 = new mascota("COBAYO","ISIDRO","BLANCO","INDEFINIDO",2);

echo $pet1->mostrar(); // Tipo: PERRO, Nombre: MILANESO, Color: NEGRO,...
echo $pet3->mostrar(); // Tipo: COBAYO, Nombre: ISIDRO, Color: BLANCO,...
```